# Are the drivers slowing down the animation playback?

Tags: animation, drivers

[image]I recently removed the drivers of a rig to discuss a problem on this same website, and I was surprised to see my playback going from 2.5 fps to 12/13 fps.

Are the drivers possibly responsible for slowing down so much my playback?

Is there a way to 'freeze' the drivers to not make them use resources (especially when animating)? Since their values stay the same all along the animation.

**EDIT:** added the picture

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hello, maybe you could rephrase the title of your question or change its body : As it is you are asking two different questions, one of which is arguably opinion-based. Cheers

Comment: You can mute drivers. You could also possibly mute whatever is beeing driven, e.g. a smooth modifier can be resource intensive.

Comment: @Gorgious hello, I am really willing to make my question as clear as possible but I don't understand your comment. I just want to know if the driver are responsible for slowing the animation playback (is it a common problem?), or is it something else (that I ignore) that cause the slowdown?

Comment: Alright, as you experienced drivers have a negative impact on performance, but how much depends on a lot of factors, like the number of drivers, the effective computations in the animation curves, and their dependencies, the modifiers, the materials, lighting, etc... As for your other question, what to do in order to prevent this, as @Leander pointed out if you go to the drivers editor you can mute and un-mute individual drivers manually

Comment: Usually drivers updating shouldn't affect your performance noticably. However, drivers usually cause something else to update often. Something else updating often can affect performance. Would be helpful to add what you are driving with the drivers.

Comment: I added a picture presenting how I use the drivers: they let me switch between various types of eyebrows, eyes and mouth, etc.
Now, I tried to close the collection where all those driven elements were and it didn't change anything to the playback. No playback improvement neither if I just solo the armature.
But if I just copy the body and the armature to another file (without the head) the playback speed multiplies by 6.
Any idea what can cause the speed shift?